# Redis [windows] deletes dump file

Tags: windows, redis

I've been using Redis for windows (v2.4) last 6 months without any issue. But in last few weeks a strange this start to happening.

My application crashes with the following message

> ServiceStack.Redis: operation not permitted, sport 58638, LastCommand:

And afterwards it deletes dump file from hdd. The only thing that restores redis is stopping windows service and restarting it with of course empty dump file

Has someone exprienced a similar issue?

**[22.1 - update]Just to update this issue with some additional info:**

there is 100gb free space on the server. Very interesting fact is that  since I restarted the redis process 2 days ago and turned on AOF the dump file was modified last time (windows file modified time) 20.1.2016 at 10:39, opposite to AOF file which was modified a minute ago.

```
The log file reports following:
[14996] 20 Jan 10:37:26 * Background AOF rewrite terminated with success
[14996] 20 Jan 10:37:26 * Parent diff successfully flushed to the rewritten AOF (0 bytes)
[14996] 20 Jan 10:37:26 # Unable to check the AOF length: Bad file descriptor
[14996] 20 Jan 10:37:26 * Background AOF rewrite successful
[14996] 20 Jan 10:37:26 # Exiting on error writing to the append-only file: Bad file descriptor
[17364] 20 Jan 10:38:34 * Server started, Redis version 2.4.5
[17364] 20 Jan 10:38:59 * DB loaded from append only file: 25 seconds
[17364] 20 Jan 10:38:59 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
[17364] 20 Jan 10:39:35 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
[17364] 20 Jan 10:39:35 * Foregroud saving started by pid 17364
[17364] 20 Jan 10:39:41 * DB saved on disk
```

Comment: do you have any further messages from the redis log?

Comment: No this is from the log file
[7796] 20 Jan 09:32:04 * DB saved on disk
[7796] 20 Jan 09:32:07 * DB saved on disk
[14996] 20 Jan 09:36:10 * Server started, Redis version 2.4.5

The redis went down at 9:33
I had AOF set to false just pure dump save

Comment: well, redis for windows behaves differently than redis for linux, in Linux this should never happen. just to make sure this isn't a security exploit - can you make sure redis' port is not exposed from the outside world?

Comment: deffo is not a security exploit. Even theoretically if someone tried to delete the whole database I should have a record trace in the log file. Anyway I turned on AOF and will see how Redis will work now.

Comment: maybe the disk is nearly full? I've seen some issues on redis for windows' github regarding stuff like that (but nothing that seems identical to your problem)

Comment: Try opening an issue for the MS developers maintaining redis for windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Memurai for Windows, a Redis-compatible cache and datastore for Windows, currently compatible with Redis 5. Memurai aims to fulfill the need for a supported Redis-compatible datastore on the Windows platform. At its core, it’s based on Redis source code, ported to run natively on Windows, and it’s designed to provide the level of reliability and performance required for production environments. Memurai is free for development and testing. You can learn more and download Memurai at https://www.memurai.com.

Disclaimer: I work in Memurai.